# Link formatting in Automator's New Mail Message

Tags: automator

I would like to send an email with automator and have a link that shows a couple words (for e.g. name of the site) instead of the whole URL like you can do with the add link inside of Mac OS.  I have tried just writing the link as HTML as shown below but that didn't work.  Is this possible?

```
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Could you please give a few more details, or explain what it is that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not possible*.

Mail's AppleScript API also does not allow for proper RTF mail. The following fails to create a proper mail body with links and everything, something clearly there in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Clipboard Viewer` (part of Xcode 4):

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theRTF to the clipboard rule «class rtf »
    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Test", content:theRTF}
    make new recipient at end of to recipients of msg with properties {address:"danielbeck@example.org"}
    send msg
end tell
```

---

You can try to use GUI scripting to copy&paste rich text using the clip board and the actual *Copy/Paste* menu items.